# ngIf not working if value contains hyphen(-) between text

Tags: javascript, angular

*ngIf not comparing value properly if value/data contains a hyphen(-) symbol i.e. 'Pick-list' in my example.

If I remove the hyphen(-) symbol then it's work.
So how to compare string which contains a hyphen(-) symbol?

```js
not working:

<ng-container *ngIf="fieldInfo.FieldType=='Pick-list'">
       <select class="form-control" required="">
       <option></option>
       <option> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
       <option> Donec imperdiet sit amet </option>
       </select>
</ng-container>
```

```js
working:

<ng-container *ngIf="fieldInfo.FieldType=='Checklist'">
       <h1>Check list</h1>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: what's the value of  fieldInfo.FieldType?

Comment: fieldInfo.FieldType = Pick-list

Comment: hyphen is not the issue. Double check your value in fieldInfo.FieldType. check the cases also

Comment: Yes I damn sure value is Pick-list, and if I remove hyphen from both side  
fieldInfo.FieldType and Picklist then it's working fine

Comment: you can check here too https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in2fav

Comment: Can you give us the output of: console.log(typeof fieldInfo.FieldType, fieldInfo.FieldType)

Comment: So Sorry guys mistake was on my side...it resolved

Comment: @pArthsavadiya then please post your mistakes.

Comment: A mistake was <select> statement inside that tag, I make it hidden from elsewhere that's why I was not able to see that select view.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing something in your code. Make sure `fieldInfo.FieldType=` has the proper value to check that you can print `((fieldInfo.FieldType}}`

Here is the working **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jshopw?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: @RishiRaut now check. seems like there was an extra space in link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the string **'Pick-list'** to a variable in your .ts file.

```
let pickList = 'Pick-list';
```

Then compare with the variable:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fieldInfo.FieldType==pickList">
       <select class="form-control" required="">
       <option></option>
       <option> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
       <option> Donec imperdiet sit amet </option>
       </select>
</ng-container>
```